# Compiling android frameworks

Tags: android, compilation, android-source

I am trying to make modifications to few files in android frameworks.
What's the fastest approach to compile a new frameworks.jar
[mm base/frameworks does not work and make is too slow]

Comment: What exactly does not work with the methods that you have tried?

Comment: What PC spec are you running the build on? Sounds like you need to think about it...

Comment: @Code-Guru mm base/frameworks does not produce a new frameworks.jar file [I verified that by deleting the file]

Comment: @t0mm13b PC specs should not matter, since I can succssfully do "make" on it. I am looking for a way to just generate frameworks.jar and everything dependent on it.

Comment: In relation to my comment, you are complaining that make is too slow - of course, the make is involved, having to compile everything to produce a frameworks.jar - in effect you are actually compiling the entire ROM, hence PC specs comes in...! Try using `export CCACHE=1` and `export CCACHE_DIR=...path...` prior to building.. and how many cpu's are you using, as in `make -jX` where X is number of cores + 1... That's what I was referring to!

Answer (score 1):

The only way to speed up the compilation of `frameworks.jar` is to do the following, which I use this Bash script and invoke this prior to calling `. build/envsetup.sh && lunch` on ArchLinux

```
#!/bin/sh
export USE_CCACHE=1
export CCACHE_DIR=/home/my_user_id/Android_Source/.ccache
/home/my_user_id/Android_Source/prebuilt/linux-x86/ccache/ccache -M 20G
```

Replace `my_user_id` with your linux id, and `Android_Source` with the appropriate location where the entire source code reside in.

This allocates a cache of 20Gb, in which common compiled objects are stashed into in order to speed up the build process.

Answer (score 0):

Try `make java`, refer to `make help` for more information.